# Can inverse of every invertible function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be drawn by reflecting that function on $y = x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an invertible function.

Can the graph of $f^{-1}$ be obtained by reflecting the graph of $f$ on the line $y = x$?

If yes then why?

Comment: Do you mean a function like $f\colon D \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow R \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes yes..@ Gibbs

Comment: Then yes, because of the construction of the inverse function. You swap domain and range, and find the inverse law. That is just the graphical representation of this process.

Comment: Can u plzz edit my qus?@Gibbs

Comment: I did not get u..can u plzz elaborate?

Comment: I have edited..Can you please unblock my question If question is clear to you?@Claude Leibovici

Comment: I have noticed people sometimes put questions on hold without clear motivations. I am sorry for this. Anyway the answer you accepted looks good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflecting the graph of a function on the line $y=x$ in order to obtain the graph of the inverse function is **bad practice**, because it mixes up the names of the variables. As long as you are talking about some $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$ at the same time you should draw just one curve. This curve then can be viewed as graph of the function $x\mapsto y=f(x)$ and at the same time as graph of the inverse function $y\mapsto x=f^{-1}(y)$, whereby you have to tilt your head $90^\circ$ in order to see the graph of $f^{-1}$ over a horizontal axis (directed to the left).

When you are through with studying how the properties of $f$ (e.g., the derivative of $\exp$) are reflected in the properties of $f^{-1}$ ($\log$ in this case) you are free to draw a standard picture of the graph of $f^{-1}$ on a second piece of paper. The resulting curve will then indeed be a mirror image of the original curve, as indicated in your question.

Comment: I tried to see $lnx$  after drawing $e^x$ by tilting my head . But I could not see $lnx$ neither in anticlockwise direction nor in clockwise. I think I misunderstood you. Can you please clear my doubt?@Christian Blatter

Comment: now I got my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because by definition $x=f^{-1}(y) \Leftrightarrow y=f(x)$, so $f$ "becomes" $f^{-1}$ if you change the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function $y=f(x)$

If $f(x)$ is invertible, you swap $y$ and $x$ to invert it and  the function will change to $x=f(y)$. Since the old $y$ is the new $x$ and vice versa, this is exactly the same as reflecting it in the line $y=x$